# Pushing a Mongo or MySQL DB from a dev environment to prod -- Ignoring rows that exist

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

I've been trying to find a way to take a database and "push" it up to a server, but have it ignore rows that collide (effectively, only inserting rows that have unique keys).  Is this possible?  I've tried Googling it a bit to no avail.

Comment: You should divide this question into two, one asking about MySQL and the other about MongoDB. Currently it can only be answered by an expert in both technologies, but separate answers for each from different people would likely be just as useful to you and others.

Comment: A fair point.  I actually did some research on this and it appears this is MongoDB's default behavior.

Comment: The best way is to take a hot backup of MySQL, through something like MySQL Admin and write a program to actually insert. The two are not compatible and mongoimport probably won't do what you want but then it is no different to writing an actual app that dioes exactly what you want, there is nothing special about it

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on your exact use case, but you could try mongoexport and mongoimport to perform this for each collection. mongoimport supports a --upsert flag that allows you to update existing documents that already exist if that is desired behavior. If not it should reject documents with the same unique key.